# Fastest seek speed and decoding with ffmpeg and x265 < ProRes

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.265, libx265, vp9

I'm trying to optimize seek speed with x265. No matter what encoding settings I try, ProRes still seeks more quickly/gracefully. This makes sense since it was built for editing, but I'm sure there's got to be something I'm missing to better improve x265.

So far, -tune fastdecode, keyint=1, maxrate and -b (to remove B Frame calculations) yield the best results, but they're still unsatisfactory. I've been pouring over the docs but there's so much jargon I just don't understand. Perhaps another codec like VP9 / WebM would be better for this purpose?

From what I can tell, there's no bottleneck with CPU, read speed or RAM... or GPU for that matter. Monitoring these processes show minimal drain. Is there just an amount of decoding in a highly compressed format like x265 that can't be circumvented?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your storage format and seek command?

Comment: Thanks for your comment --> I'm on Ubuntu, ext4 and using input-fast-seek in libVLC

Comment: Your stream storage format i.e. container, and how fast does ffplay seek?

Comment: Ah, sorry -- I've tried .mov and .mkv and I'm trying to avoid using ffmpeg since it seems rather daunting. I built this program I'm testing with libVLC.